# Positioning in a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, position, android-constraintlayout

I have three views: a `TextView`, a `LinearLayout` and a `Switch` inside a `ConstraintLayout`:

```xml
<merge xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Some text" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text5" />

            
        </LinearLayout>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

I want the `TextView` to be 15dp from the left, the `LinearLayout` at the centre and the `Switch` 15dp from the right. But they all are on the left. I tried using `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for all the three views, changing some attributes and constraints, but none of them worked, though some were displayed as expected in Android Studio's layout preview, but they clutter to the left at runtime. I'm not sure if `ConstraintLayout` is the best option either. As you can see, this is for a custom view.